# how to cancel XmlRpcClient.execute before timeout (java)

Tags: java, thread-safety, xml-rpc, vpn, cancel-button

I'm programming in java and am using XML-RPC to submit data from a client to a server. My problem is that when I XmlRpcClient.execute code but whenever I have a connection error, the application gets stuck until I eventually get a Timeout exception (which I want). I placed this whole process in a new thread and wanted the ability to stop/cancel the process if I didn't want to wait for the timeout.

I learned how to stop Threads but idk if I can interrupt the XmlRpcClient.execute code.

any ideas?

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The default `execute` method is, by nature, synchronous, that is, blocking.
If you are using Jakarta Commons HttpClient, you could set the socket timeout to a shorter value (the default is 0 meaning no timeout) with the transport's `setConnectionTimeout` method.
I believe, though, that the proper handling would be to use the `executeAsync` method and providing a callback to it in order to continue.